# How to restart/loop a window.onload javascript program without reloading the webpage

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript program to change the background of my website every 4 seconds, and it starts right as the page loads so its automatic. I was wondering if there is a way to make it start over 4 secs after it displays the last image. The ways I have tried don't work, and I think its because the program will only run when the page is loaded/reloaded, so if there is another (simple) way to start the program without window.onload that would allow me to restart the program without reloading the page, I would love to know!

Here's my code:

```
window.onload = function timer() {
setTimeout(change1, 4000) 
setTimeout(change2, 8000) 
setTimeout(change3, 12000) 
setTimeout(change4, 16000) 
setTimeout(change5, 20000) 
setTimeout(change6, 24000) 
setTimeout(change7, 28000) 
setTimeout(change8, 32000) 
setTimeout(change9, 36000) 
setTimeout(change10, 40000) 
setTimeout(change11, 40001)
}
function change1() {
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/battlefield1.jpg')";
}
function change2() {
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/battlefront.jpg')";
}
function change3() {
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/gtav.jpg')";
}
function change4() {
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/doom4.jpg')";
}
function change5() {
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/darksouls.jpg')";
}
function change6() {
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/civVI.jpg')";
}
function change7() {
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/stardew.jpg')";
}
function change8() {
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/superhot.jpg')";
}
function change9() {
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/watchdogs.jpg')";
}
function change10() {
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/mafia.jpg')";
}
function change11() {
timer();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just have the functions call each other via `setTimeout` (so `change10` then triggers `change1`)? (Also I would highly advise refactoring this, it looks pretty messy for something that only changes the background image)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```js
function timer() {
  setTimeout(change1, 4000)
  setTimeout(change2, 8000)
  setTimeout(change3, 12000)
  setTimeout(change4, 16000)
  setTimeout(change5, 20000)
  setTimeout(change6, 24000)
  setTimeout(change7, 28000)
  setTimeout(change8, 32000)
  setTimeout(change9, 36000)
  setTimeout(change10, 40000)
  setTimeout(change11, 40001)
}

function change1() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/battlefield1.jpg')";
  console.log("change1")
}

function change2() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/battlefront.jpg')";
  console.log("change2")
}

function change3() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/gtav.jpg')";
  console.log("change3")
}

function change4() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/doom4.jpg')";
}

function change5() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/darksouls.jpg')";
}

function change6() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/civVI.jpg')";
}

function change7() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/stardew.jpg')";
}

function change8() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/superhot.jpg')";
}

function change9() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/watchdogs.jpg')";
}

function change10() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/mafia.jpg')";
}

function change11() {
  console.log("change11")
  timer();
}

timer();
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```